# Query Error: error: syntax error at or near "SELECT"

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, subquery

I am trying 8weeksqlchallenge, and I usually work with MySQL and the error codes are quite cleaner there, but not so much on dbfiddle.com

This is my schema

```
CREATE SCHEMA dannys_diner;
SET search_path = dannys_diner;

CREATE TABLE sales 
(
    "customer_id" VARCHAR(1),
    "order_date" DATE,
    "product_id" INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO sales ("customer_id", "order_date", "product_id")
VALUES
  ('A', '2021-01-01', '1'),
  ('A', '2021-01-01', '2'),
  ('A', '2021-01-07', '2'),
  ('A', '2021-01-10', '3'),
  ('A', '2021-01-11', '3'),
  ('A', '2021-01-11', '3'),
  ('B', '2021-01-01', '2'),
  ('B', '2021-01-02', '2'),
  ('B', '2021-01-04', '1'),
  ('B', '2021-01-11', '1'),
  ('B', '2021-01-16', '3'),
  ('B', '2021-02-01', '3'),
  ('C', '2021-01-01', '3'),
  ('C', '2021-01-01', '3'),
  ('C', '2021-01-07', '3');
 
CREATE TABLE menu 
(
    "product_id" INTEGER,
    "product_name" VARCHAR(5),
    "price" INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO menu ("product_id", "product_name", "price")
VALUES
  ('1', 'sushi', '10'),
  ('2', 'curry', '15'),
  ('3', 'ramen', '12');
  

CREATE TABLE members 
(
    "customer_id" VARCHAR(1),
    "join_date" DATE
);

INSERT INTO members ("customer_id", "join_date")
VALUES
  ('A', '2021-01-07'),
  ('B', '2021-01-09');
```

And ask was to find the first product purchased by each customer, so I thought of going with subquery with following code, but it returned

> Query Error: error: syntax error at or near "SELECT"

```
SELECT sales.customer_id, sales.product_id
FROM dannys_diner.sales 
WHERE sales.order_date = SELECT MIN(sales.order_date)
                         FROM dannys_diner.sales 
                         GROUP BY sales.customer_id;
```

Comment: please execute your SELECT MIN(sales.order_date)
FROM dannys_diner.sales 
GROUP BY sales.customer_id   and see that you have several dates. I suspect even if you fix syntax error you will get the incorrect result

Comment: What would be the correct answer for A? 1, 2 or 1 and 2

Answer (score 2):

There are two syntax errors here.

First, the subquery needs to be enclosed in parentheses. This is easily remedied.

Second, in order to be valid on the right-hand side of the equality comparison with `sales.order_date`, the subquery *must* be guaranteed to always return a single value. The `GROUP BY` clause in the subquery breaks this, because it allows for separate minimum order dates per customer id. This is trickier to resolve, because it means re-thinking the structure of the query.

Instead, I suggest using a `row_number()` window function you to identify rows by date, and then show the product from the rows without needing a correlated per-row subquery or JOIN (in other words, it should be **much** faster):

```
SELECT customer_id, product_id
FROM (
    select sales.customer_id, sales.product_id
        , row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by sales.order_date) rn
    from dannys_diner.sales
) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

> https://dbfiddle.uk/YGdol5Rd

Comment: [Also, a note on my use of capitalization](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2023/03/08/improving-readability-of-complex-nested-sql/)

Comment: I think for simple cases the indenting is enough but I might use this trick in a really complex query -- nice idea Joel.

Comment: This one becomes slower over time, when more records are added.

Answer (score 0):

You need `(` and `)` around the sub-query -- like this

```
SELECT sales.customer_id, sales.product_id
FROM dannys_diner.sales
WHERE sales.order_date = ( 
  SELECT MIN(sales.order_date)
  FROM dannys_diner.sales 
  GROUP BY sales.customer_id
);
```

As some have noted there might be data that would cause a problem a join solves this because you can make sure the min number is by customer_id -- like this

```
SELECT sales.customer_id, sales.product_id
FROM dannys_diner.sales
JOIN ( 
  SELECT MIN(sales.order_date) as order_date, sales.customer_id
  FROM dannys_diner.sales 
  GROUP BY sales.customer_id
) as x on x.order_date = sales.order_date and x.customer_id = sales.customer_id ;
```

Note if you compare a fiddle using my code

https://dbfiddle.uk/CSKDTxd6

To Joel's answer (using a windowing function) you can see we get different results -- I will return more than one row if they have the same date -- his will only ever return one row.  Pick which one meets your requirements:

Comment: a GROUP BY returns multiple columns so this brings an error

Comment: @Hogan. I guess, the issue is that for customer 1 min date is 1 January, but for customer 2 min date is 1 August

Comment: The subquery returns one record for each sales.customer_id. The outer query excepts only one result. This conflict will result in an error.

Comment: I wrote a fix guys -- thanks for the comments :)

Answer (score 0):

you can join the subqzery to get your wanted result

```
SELECT s1.customer_id, s1.product_id
FROM dannys_diner.sales s1 JOIN
  (SELECT customer_id,MIN(order_date) min_date
FROM dannys_diner.sales 
GROUP BY sales.customer_id) s2  ON s1.customer_id = s2.customer_id
  ANd s1.order_date = s2.min_date
  
;
```

| customer_id | product_id |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 3 |
| C | 3 |

> ```
> SELECT 5
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/QLeokBxR)

Comment: Isn't this the same as my answer with bad indenting?